# Nx set NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size for Angular app

Tags: angular, devops, nrwl-nx

I have an Angular application in an [Nx](https://nx.dev/) workspace that is built using the `@nx/angular:webpack-browser` executor.

```json
"build": {
  "executor": "@nx/angular:webpack-browser",
...
}
```

This is a large application and requires `NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size` to be set to a larger value.
Until now I used `set` and `export` to set the value of this flag in Windows/Linux and then run the build command.

The first command was

```
set NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=MY_VALUE`
```

and the second was

```
npm run build -- MY_APP
```

which translates to `nx build`.

I would like to get rid of the first command and set the flag from the `project.json` file. I tried with a custom executor and `cross-env' [package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env), but no luck.

```json
"node-options": {
  "executor": "nx:run-commands",
  "options": {
    "command": "cross-env NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=5000"
    }
  },
"build": {
  "executor": "@nx/angular:webpack-browser",
  "dependsOn": ["^build", "node-options"],
...
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Why not have booth in the same `scripts` entry in the `package.json` ?

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler this is an option, but since this is an Nx workspace, there may be the scenario where I don't need to set this flag for all applications, but only for this one, and that's why I want to do the update in the `project.json' of this application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nx will load environment variables from `.env` files. It also supports [a hierarchy of files](https://nx.dev/recipes/tips-n-tricks/define-environment-variables).

So just add `NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=5000` to `apps/my-app/.env` for example